# jquery data-attribute works randomly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a function which is called on mouse out.
It checks whether the element is now "dragged" or in process of editing. If not it should remove the active state.

This is how it looks.

```
function onMouseOut() {
        console.log("mouse out");
        if ($(this).find(".content").attr('data-editing') != "true" && $(this).find(".content").attr('data-dragging') != "true") {
                console.log("no edit, no dragging");
                removeActive($(this).find(".content"));
        } else {
                console.log("edit: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-editing"));
                console.log("dragging: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-draging"));
        }
}
```

The element is inside a sortable. It does not break the code above and I can sort it as many times as I want. But when I add the "connectWith" and shift sender it totally breaks.

Then my output to console is as follows:

```
mouse out
edit: undefined
dragging: undefined
```

Now, how is that even possible?

**EDIT:**

Ok here comes the markup:

```
<div id="body">
    <section class="main_1 grid_8 field" data-field='main_1'>
        <div class='module'>
        <div class="content content-editor" data-id='1' data-module='content' contenteditable='true'>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1><p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class='module'>
        <div class="content content-editor" data-id='4' data-module='content' contenteditable='true'>
            <h4>Yet another content</h4><p>This is yet another contentblock!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside class="aside_1 grid_4 field" data-field='aside_1'>
        <div class='module'>
        <div class="content content-editor" data-id='2' data-module='content' contenteditable='true'>
            <h2>Aside Content</h2><p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <div class="x-clear"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    /*
    * - on hoover, we display the panel
    */
    $( ".content-editor" ).mouseenter(onMouseIn);
    $( ".edit-wrap" ).live("mouseleave", onMouseOut);

    /*
    * - on click/focus, we set it as active
    */
    $( ".content-editor" ).focus(onFocus);
    $( ".content-editor" ).blur(onLostFocus);
});


/*
* - functions
*/
function onMouseIn() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-active') != "true" && !dragging) {
        console.log("wasnt active: " + $(this).attr('data-active'));
        makeActive($(this));
    } else {
        console.log("was active: " + $(this).data('id') + " - act: " + $(this).attr('data-active'));
    }
}
function onMouseOut() {
    console.log("mouse out");
    if ($(this).find(".content").attr('data-editing') != "true" && $(this).find(".content").attr('data-dragging') != "true") {
        console.log("no edit, no dragging");
        removeActive($(this).find(".content"));
    } else {
        console.log("edit: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-editing"));
        console.log("dragging: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-draging"));
    }
}
function onFocus() {
    $(this).attr('data-editing', 'true');
}
function onLostFocus() {
    console.log("lost focus: " + $(this).data('id'));
}
function makeActive($this) {
    $this.attr('data-active', "true");

    $this.wrap("<div class='edit-wrap'>");
    var $parent = $this.parent(".edit-wrap");

    $parent.prepend("<div class='edit-head'>&raquo; Content ( Quick Edit )</div>");
    $parent.append(editMenu);
}
function removeActive($this) {
    $this.parent(".edit-wrap").find(".edit-head").remove();
    $this.parent(".edit-wrap").find(".edit-menu").remove();

    $this.unwrap(".edit-wrap");
    $this.attr('data-active', "false");
}


/*
* - html
*/
var editMenu = "<div class='edit-menu'>"+
        "<a href='#' class='btn openEditor'>Ã–ppna Editor</a>"+
        "<a href='#' class='btn quicksave'>Snabspara</a>"+
        "</div>";
```

and:

```
    var dragging = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
    $( ".edit-head" ).live("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).parent(".edit-wrap").draggable({
            handle: ".edit-head",
            revert: 'invalid'
        }); 
    });

    $( ".edit-wrap" ).live("dragstart", function() {
        $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "true");
    });
    $( ".edit-wrap" ).live("dragstop", function() {
        $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "false");
        removeActive($(this).find(".content"));
    });
    */

    $( ".field" ).sortable({
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
            $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "true");
            dragging = true;

            $(".field").addClass("target");

        },
        stop: function() {
            $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "false");
            dragging = false;

            $(".field").removeClass("target");
        },
        connectWith: '.field',
        placeholder: "drop-placeholder",
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        handle: ".edit-head",

        update: function(e, ui) {
            var $this   = ui.item;
            var $sender = ui.sender;

            if ($sender) {
                //vi bytte field
                console.log("bytte");
            } else {
                console.log("bytte inte");
            }
            console.log("change: " + $this + " from: " + $sender);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: post your markup as well

Comment: On a general note, you should not work with `.attr('data-foo')`. Just use `.data('foo')`. Also remember that data names coming from HTML markup always are lower-case in jQuery, no matter what case they are in the HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

Look for typos:

```
attr("data-draging")
```

and somewhere else in your code

```
attr("data-dragging")
```

However as said, use:

```
data("dragging")
```

Comment: I swop all data-dragging attributes to a global "dragging" variable and that seemed to do the trick. Possible the problem was typos.

I don't see how to use the data() though.. (that's how I started and it caused me a lot of headache till I tested the following)

        $("body").attr("data-test", "testing");
        console.log("test: " + $("body").data("test"));
        $("body").attr("data-test", "more testing");
        console.log("test: " + $("body").data("test"));
        $("body").attr("data-test", "omg more ?");
        console.log("test: " + $("body").data("test"));

Comment: which has the following output:

testing
testing
testing

Answer (score 0):

For one thing I'd suggest not to overload your HTML with data attributes but use default attributes such as `id` and `class` (for the active/dragging state for example). Second you write really slow code when using `$(this).find()` all the time, you can give the context of a selector in jQuery and you can also cache your objects/data: `var $content = $('.content', this);`. This makes your code cleaner (`$(this).is('.active')` instead of checking the data-active string) and perhaps even sorts out coding mistakes.

PS: if you're using recent jQuery versions, do also update your jQuery coding knowledge :) (e.g. read the docs)

Comment: I really appreciate this advice. I will go through my code and change to this approach. However I cannot mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sure not, I just noticed that it was a bit long for a simple comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you keep using data attributes as much as you want and keep class'es mostly for styling BUT access data attrabutes with:

```
$selector.data("name")
```

method rather than

```
$selector.attr("data-name")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("dragging: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-draging"));
```

typo, needs to be

```
console.log("dragging: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging"));
```

this is why you're getting the undefined in the console.

the "data-editing" attribute check in onMouseOut could be undefined if it was never set. I defaulted it to false. you might want that to default the value in the HTML element or you may want to check for undefined in your if statement.

```
$( ".content-editor" ).attr('data-editing', 'false');
```

change the stop to get event and ui as well sort(e,ui) and set data-dragging attr ui.item (the current dragging item) to false.

```
 stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.item).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "false");
        $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "false");
```

it isn't setting the element you're dragging to false it seems to be setting it for the elements that are being shifted around to false.

There seems to still be an issue with it getting into "edit mode" I'm not sure if blur is  handling this event well. I'll update late when I have more time.

ALL TOGETHER NOW:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /*
    * - on hoover, we display the panel
    */
    $( ".content-editor" ).mouseenter(onMouseIn);
    $( ".content-editor" ).attr('data-editing', 'false');
    $( ".edit-wrap" ).live("mouseleave", onMouseOut);

    /*
    * - on click/focus, we set it as active
    */
    $( ".content-editor" ).focus(onFocus);
    $( ".content-editor" ).blur(onLostFocus);
});


/*
* - functions
*/
function onMouseIn() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-active') != "true" && !dragging) {
        console.log("wasnt active: " + $(this).attr('data-active'));
        makeActive($(this));
    } else {
        console.log("was active: " + $(this).data('id') + " - act: " + $(this).attr('data-active'));
    }
}
function onMouseOut() {
    console.log("mouse out");
    if ($(this).find(".content").attr('data-editing') != "true" && $(this).find(".content").attr('data-dragging') != "true") {
        console.log("no edit, no dragging");
        removeActive($(this).find(".content"));
    } else {
        console.log("edit: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-editing"));
        console.log("dragging: " + $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging"));
    }
}
function onFocus() {
    $(this).attr('data-editing', 'true');
}
function onLostFocus() {
    console.log("lost focus: " + $(this).data('id'));
    //$(this).attr('data-editing', 'false');
}
function makeActive($this) {
    $this.attr('data-active', "true");

    $this.wrap("<div class='edit-wrap'>");
    var $parent = $this.parent(".edit-wrap");

    $parent.prepend("<div class='edit-head'>&raquo; Content ( Quick Edit )</div>");
    $parent.append(editMenu);
}
function removeActive($this) {
    $this.parent(".edit-wrap").find(".edit-head").remove();
    $this.parent(".edit-wrap").find(".edit-menu").remove();

    $this.unwrap(".edit-wrap");
    $this.attr('data-active', "false");
}


/*
* - html
*/
var editMenu = "<div class='edit-menu'>"+
        "<a href='#' class='btn openEditor'>Ã–ppna Editor</a>"+
        "<a href='#' class='btn quicksave'>Snabspara</a>"+
        "</div>";


  var dragging = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    /*
    $( ".edit-head" ).live("mouseover", function() {
        $(this).parent(".edit-wrap").draggable({
            handle: ".edit-head",
            revert: 'invalid'
        });
    });

    $( ".edit-wrap" ).live("dragstart", function() {
        $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "true");
    });
    $( ".edit-wrap" ).live("dragstop", function() {
        $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "false");
        removeActive($(this).find(".content"));
    });
    */

    $( ".field" ).sortable({
        start: function(e, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
            $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "true");
            dragging = true;

            $(".field").addClass("target");

        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
            $(ui.item).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "false");
            $(this).find(".content").attr("data-dragging", "false");

            dragging = false;

            $(".field").removeClass("target");
        },
        connectWith: '.field',
        placeholder: "drop-placeholder",
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        handle: ".edit-head",

        update: function(e, ui) {
            var $this   = ui.item;
            var $sender = ui.sender;

            if ($sender) {
                //vi bytte field
                console.log("bytte");
            } else {
                console.log("bytte inte");
            }
            console.log("change: " + $this + " from: " + $sender);
        }
    });
});
```